# AccessViolationException when using PInvoke on functions with parameters

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am currently using PInvoke to call some unmanaged functions from C++ in C#; specifically from PhysX 3.3.3.  I am relatively new to PInvoke so I started with some simple methods.  I can easily call functions that take no parameters but am having trouble calling any that do.

Starting simple, I used a function that passed in a boolean and discovered that booleans are non-blittable types so they must be marshaled.  However, adding the boolean marshaling to the PInvoke signature still did not work.

```
[DllImport("PhysX3CommonCHECKED_x64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
           EntryPoint = "?getReportAllocationNames@Foundation@shdfnd@physx@@UEBA_NXZ")]
public static extern bool GetAllocationNames();

[DllImport("PhysX3CommonCHECKED_x64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
           EntryPoint = "?setReportAllocationNames@Foundation@shdfnd@physx@@UEAAX_N@Z")]
public static extern void SetAllocationNames([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]bool name);
```

When I call *SetAllocationNames(true)*, I get an **AccessViolationException**. I have also tried using other member names for the UnmanagedType enumeration (e.g. U1, Bool) but to no avail.

I am loading the DLLs prior to calling the functions, I am using the correct mangled name as the entry point, and I am calling all parameters associated with this function (just one in this case). Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure you have C calling convention and decorated names?!

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Pinvoke is fine with parameters. @Robert However, it looks like `setReportAllocationNames` is a virtual method to be defined by an inheritor class. Have you done this work correctly?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use the full name of the entry point.  The C++ code should have a label on the method as an entry point.  This would put the name of method in the symbol list in side the dll.  You will get an access violation if the method isn't public.

Comment: @whoisj  It is indeed a virtual method but the function should be called by the inheritor class.

Comment: I try to make myself clear: you cannot pinvoke c++ instance methods (unless you schedule much much more effort). Moreover thiscall c.c. isn't supported with pinvoke. Use c++/cli or export c functions.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti How do you know that it isn't supported by PInvoke? Are not all exposed functions supported? Also, what do you mean by "c.c."?

Comment: @jdweng From my understanding, unless the function uses 'extern "C" ' to indicate C linkage, you will need to use the full mangled name. I don't see any other explicit label in the C++ code.

Comment: There are sometimes more than on pseudo-op that can be used.  Declaring an Entry Point is equivalent to an extern.  But if a  method isn't public you have to follow Adriano response.  If you compile with the MAP option,  it will  give all the info you need.

Comment: @robert cc is calling convention. Name decoration, who cleans stack, how and where parameters and return value are passed. With pinvoke you can't do thisc

Comment: Can't do thiscall without much more effort (because...this in c# and this in c++ are very different things, just think about virtual and multiple inheritance).

Comment: What I want to say: it's c++ class? Wrap it in a managed class with c++/cli or export c functions.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Thanks for the advice but I'm still a little unclear. CallingConvention is supported by PInvoke, according to Microsoft's documentation. Also, from my understanding, mangled names are used because inheritance and overloaded functions exists in C++. I add the name in the Entry Point to clarify which function to use.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Absolutely right. Now think what "this" pointer is. Think about its size (mixing one or more base classes and with or without public inheritance). Now think about vtable structure (no common abi even in native world). Now transpose everything to c#! How you control that stuff? "this" in clrcall cc is *completely* different. You have to invoke constructor, pass somehow this pointer (in registry) and then *maybe* it will work! Possible. Not easy. Same thing in stdcall or cdecl or fastcall is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Errata: virtual, not public, inheritance

Comment: It's way more than the this pointer. Virtual methods for a start. And how are you going to invoke a C++ constructor?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, I mentioned vtable in another comment. Well it's _possible_ to pinvoke constructor (`??0Foundation@...`) after you allocated memory for its vtable (non standard! compiler dependent! brainkiller game for multiple/virtual inheritance!) with `Memory.Alloc` and manually fill it... You then use `ThisCall` for everything and add a parameter to your "vtable" struct to each method. Method invocation in vtable (all but ctor and dtor) via `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`. OK, it's crazy...that's why _"...much more effort..."_ unless you do it just for fun...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is mostly impossible to share C++ libraries with other C++ applications *if they were compiled with a different compiler* (and even worse, different versions of the same compiler) , yet alone using `PInvoke`.

Secondly, you're not even close at tackling this problem. C++'s calling convention (in x86) for methods (functions that belong to a class) is [thiscall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8tkfbw.aspx), which means that `this` (the class the method is called upon) is passed via the `ecx` or `rcx` register. `cdecl` doesn't pass one. Secondly, you didn't even define the appropriate classes...

**What you should do is to write a C++ wrapper**

Write functions, not methods (i.e - not bound to any class or struct), that do whatever you need to be done, and make sure that you know their calling convention (make it something conventional, like `cdecl` or `fastcall`). This way you can write C/C++ code to do the work for you, and write `C#` with `PInvoke`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I understand now. After further research, it does seem that inherited functions are problematic for PInvoke. Many sources recommend flattening the C++ code to a C style interface. I will have to use a C++/CLI project instead. Thanks!